# How can I pad a series of hyphen-separated numbers each to two digits?

Tags: string, powershell, pad, zero-padding

I am fairly new to PowerShell programming, so need help with set of strings I have as described below:

```
"14-2-1-1"
"14-2-1-1-1"
"14-2-1-1-10"
```

I want to pad zero to each number in between `-` if that number is between `1` and `9`. So the result should look like:

```
"14-02-01-01"
"14-02-01-01-01"
"14-02-01-01-10"
```

I came up with the following code but was wondering if there is a better/faster solution.

```powershell
$Filenum = "14-2-1-1"
$hicount = ($Filenum.ToCharArray() | Where-Object{$_ -eq '-'} | Measure-Object).Count
$FileNPad = ''
For ($i=0; $i -le $hicount; $i++) {
    $Filesec= "{$i}" -f $Filenum.split('-')
    If ([int]$Filesec -le 9)
    {
        $FileNPad = "$FileNPad-"+"0"+"$Filesec"
    }
    Else
    {
        $FileNPad="$FileNPad-$Filesec"
    }
}
$FileNPad = $FileNPad.Trim("-"," ")
```

Comment: Figured out a way, But if anyone can think of better/faster solution please keep me posted!!

$Filenum = "14-2-1-1"
$hicount  = ($Filenum.ToCharArray() | Where-Object{$_ -eq '-'} | Measure-Object).Count  $FileNPad = ''
For ($i=0; $i -le $hicount; $i++)
{
  $Filesec= "{$i}" -f $Filenum.split('-')
  If ([int]$Filesec -le 9){$FileNPad = "$FileNPad-"+"0"+"$Filesec"}
  Else {$FileNPad="$FileNPad-$Filesec"}
}
$FileNPad = $FileNPad.Trim("-"," ")

Comment: Please don't post answers as comments. Do it as an answer.

Comment: I incorporated the code from your comment into your question, but you should still define what a "better/faster solution" would be.  Better _how_?  Less memory usage, less processor usage, less code, clearer code?  Faster _than what_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to manually keep track of how many elements and inspect each value, you can simply split on `-`, padleft, then join back together with `-`

```
"14-2-1-1","14-2-1-1-1","14-2-1-1-10" | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -split '-').PadLeft(2,'0') -join '-'
}
```

Which outputs

```
14-02-01-01
14-02-01-01-01
14-02-01-01-10
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the responce. I loved your suggestion of PadLeft method, simple and easy to follow... Much appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to go with something like [Doug Maurer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613225/150605) due to its clarity, but here's another way to look at this.  The last section below shows a solution that might be just as clear with some advantages of its own.

### Pattern of digit groups in the input

Your input strings are composed of one or more groups, where each group...

1. ...contains one or more digits, and...
2. ...is preceded by a `-` or the beginning of the string, and...
3. ...is followed by a `-` or the end of the string.

Groups that require a leading `"0"` to be inserted contain exactly one digit; that is, they consist of...

1. ...a `-` or the beginning of the string, followed by...
2. ...a single digit, followed by...
3. ...a `-` or the end of the string.

### Replacing single-digit digit groups using the `-replace` operator

We can use [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) with the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) to locate that pattern and replace the single digit with a `"0"` followed by that same digit...

```powershell
'0-0-0-0', '00-00-00-00', '1-2-3-4', '01-02-03-04', '10-20-30-40', '11-22-33-44' |
    ForEach-Object -Process { $_ -replace '(?<=-|^)(\d)(?=-|$)', '0$1' }
```

...which outputs...

```
00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00
01-02-03-04
01-02-03-04
10-20-30-40
11-22-33-44
```

As the documentation describes, the `-replace` operator is used like this...

> `<input> -replace <regular-expression>, <substitute>`

#### The match pattern

The match pattern `'(?<=-|^)(\d)(?=-|$)'` means...

- `(?<=-|^)`: A [zero-width positive lookbehind assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-positive-lookbehind-assertions) for either `-` or the beginning of the string

  - In other words, match but don't capture either `-` or the beginning of the string
- `(\d)`: A single [digit](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#decimal-digit-character-d), [captured](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#matched_subexpression) and made available with the replacement [substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-a-numbered-group) `$1`
- `(?=-|$)`: A [zero-width positive lookahead assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-positive-lookahead-assertions) for either `-` or the end of the string

  - In other words, match but don't capture either `-` or the end of the string

#### The replacement pattern

The replacement pattern `'0$1'` means...

- The literal text `'0'`, followed by...
- The value of the first capture (`(\d)`)

### Replacing single-digit digit groups using `[Regex]::Replace()` and a replacement `[String]`

Instead of the `-replace` operator you can also call the `static` [`Replace()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-string)) of the [`[Regex]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex)...

```powershell
'0-0-0-0', '00-00-00-00', '1-2-3-4', '01-02-03-04', '10-20-30-40', '11-22-33-44' |
    ForEach-Object -Process { [Regex]::Replace($_, '(?<=-|^)(\d)(?=-|$)', '0$1') }
```

...and the result is the same.

### Replacing digit groups using `[Regex]::Replace()` and a `[MatchEvaluator]`

A hybrid of the regular expression and [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) solutions is to call [an overload of the `Replace()` method that takes a `[MatchEvaluator]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) instead of a replacement `[String]`...

```powershell
# This [ScriptBlock] will be passed to a [System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator] parameter
$matchEvaluator = {
    # The [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match] parameter
    param($match)

    # The replacement [String]
    return $match.Value.PadLeft(2, '0')
}

'0-0-0-0', '00-00-00-00', '1-2-3-4', '01-02-03-04', '10-20-30-40', '11-22-33-44' |
    ForEach-Object -Process { [Regex]::Replace($_, '(\d+)', $matchEvaluator) }
```

This produces the same result as above.

A [`[MatchEvaluator]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator) is a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.delegate) that takes a [`Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) to be replaced (`$match`) and returns the `[String]` with which to replace it (the [matched text](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value) left-padded to two digits).  Also note that, whereas above we are capturing only standalone digits `(\d)`, here we capture all groups of one or more digits `(\d+)` and leave it to [`PadLeft()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft) to figure out if a leading `"0"` is needed.

I think this is a much more compelling solution than regular expressions alone because it's the best of that and the [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) world:

- It uses a simple regular expression pattern to locate digit groups in the input string
- It uses a simple `[ScriptBlock]` to transform digit groups in the input string
- By not splitting the input string apart it does not create as much intermediate string and array [garbage](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/)

  - Whether this potential performance improvement is overshadowed by using regular expressions at all, I can't say without benchmarking

Comment: Some really amazing suggestions and insight. Thanks alot.